# Why is image that fits inside of div is expanding div for IE 8 on WIndows XP

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, css-float, windows-xp

Here's the source code:

```
<div id="myID1" class="AutoDiv-small"
  style="left:547.5px; top:41px;  width:380px; height:445px;">
    <div id="TitleBar" class="PopupTitleBar"
      style="width: 100%; height: 20px; line-height: 15px;
      font-weight: bold; text-align: center; verticle-align: middle;
      background-image: URL('images/title bar.png');
      background-repeat: repeat-x;">My Title<a onclick="HideContent(myID1);" href=#>
        <img style="float: right; padding: 1px;" border=0
          src="images/close_red.png">
        </a>
    </div>
    //Lot's of other content
</div>
```

It looks fine on everything but IE8 on XP; everything newer than IE8 on XP.  I have to get it to display correctly on this browser too.

"Fine" means that it displays on the same line as the text and inside the background on the right side.

IE8 is pushing the image down a line, which puts it outside the background image and pushes the rest of the content inside a containing div down too.

Comment: You are missing closing <div>

Comment: Thank you.  The suggested edit got it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use tables, I dont get that problem with tables. I made you a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TKvGj/. Here is the basic table structure for you:

```
<table style="width:300px">
<tr>
  <td>Your text here</td>
  <td><a onclick="HideContent(myID1);" href=#><img style="float: right; padding: 1px;" border=0 src="http://avatarmaker.net/free-avatars/avatars/animated_214/sleepy_cat_animated_avatar_100x100_29622.gif" /></a></td>     
  </tr>
</table>
```

That works fine for me. Hope I answered your question.

Comment: I was hoping not to use tables.  I've already got a lot of code written around using divs.

Comment: Well that is the best answer I've got. Maybe you can use `max-width` and `max-height`.

Comment: How familiar are you with IE8?  It may be my only option.  `max-height` didn't do anything when I added it to the image.  Maybe the div would work.

Comment: I wasn't sure if that would work in any browser. I would use tables.